# Compare two IDs within a group and outputting matches in R

Tags: r, duplicates

Below is the top of a data frame showing ties between people within different countries. These countries are mini police states with high border walls. This means that an `ego_id` from `ego_country` 1 can *never* be associated with an `alter_id` that appears in another `ego_country`. For convenience, I have put brackets around `alter_id's` that violate this logic. The full data frame is about 100k rows long, and includes observations for 120 countries.

```
ego_id  alter_id    ego_country
120     121         1
120     122         1
121     120         1
122     122         1
122     123         1
122    [121]        1
123     120         1
123     121         1
214     217         2
214     218         2
214    [121]        2
217     214         2
217     218         2
218     214         2
320     322         3
...     ...         ...
```

I need to check for violations of the logic I specify above, and output the rows where an `alter_id` has shown up in more than one `ego_country`. What are some approaches for doing so?

Comment: Could you use `dput` to provide a sample of your data frame so this problem is reproducible? Also might be useful too have additional examples of the violation of logic in it. It looks like you just want to find `alter_id` that appear in more than one `ego_country`?

Comment: That's exactly right - thanks for checking. I'll use `dput` on a portion of my data frame when I get back to a computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post approaches your question from a couple different perspectives, culminating in "just flag the original data frame if there's a dupe in a different country." I've broken it into a few different pieces so you are better able to identify how to map these solutions to your original problem:

Find dupes of `alter_id` across different countries:

```
> library(dplyr)
> z <- ego %>% group_by(alter_id,ego_country) %>% summarize(count=n()) 
> duplicated(z$alter_id)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> z[duplicated(z$alter_id),]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   alter_id [1]
  alter_id ego_country count
     <int>       <int> <int>
1      121           2     1
```

Or narrow down to the duplicate `alter_id` alone:

```
> z[duplicated(z$alter_id),]$alter_id
[1] 121
```

Make a column that flags dupes:

```
> ego %>% group_by(alter_id,ego_country) %>% summarize(count=n()) %>% 
               mutate(dupes=duplicated(alter_id))
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   alter_id [8]
  alter_id ego_country count dupes
     <int>       <int> <int> <lgl>
1      120           1     2 FALSE
2      121           1     3 FALSE
3      121           2     1 TRUE 
4      122           1     2 FALSE
5      123           1     1 FALSE
6      214           2     2 FALSE
7      217           2     1 FALSE
8      218           2     2 FALSE
9      322           3     1 FALSE
```

Once you have the dupes identified in `z`, you can also alter the original data frame with a field to flag whether that observation appears in another country. You'll notice only `alter_id` of `121` are flagged when they appear in multiple countries:

```
> dupe_id <- z[duplicated(z$alter_id),]$alter_id
> ego %>% mutate(dupes=ifelse(alter_id %in% dupe_id,"TRUE","FALSE"))
   ego_id alter_id ego_country dupes
1     120      121           1  TRUE
2     120      122           1 FALSE
3     121      120           1 FALSE
4     122      122           1 FALSE
5     122      123           1 FALSE
6     122      121           1  TRUE
7     123      120           1 FALSE
8     123      121           1  TRUE
9     214      217           2 FALSE
10    214      218           2 FALSE
11    214      121           2  TRUE
12    217      214           2 FALSE
13    217      218           2 FALSE
14    218      214           2 FALSE
15    320      322           3 FALSE
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed - and more, in fact. Thanks a lot for your answer!